# Program in to generate chained list in python

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree

I am developing a program in python and as part of it I have to link all the lists that have an element in common in a certain position, that is, there is an input element and an output element and I want to gather all those that follow the chain. For example, we have as input a list :

```
list_array = [[n_element, l_input, l_ouput], .....]
```

A concrete example would be

```
list_array = [[1,a,b],[2,c,d],[3,e,f],[4,b,e],[5,d,f],[6,a,e],[7,b,c]
```

The result of the program should be a list where the elements are linked by input and output.

```
res_array = [[1,4,3],[1,7,2,5],[6,3]]
```

The result of the program should be a list where the elements are linked by input and output. If there is one element included in another, the element with greater length prevails. My first thought was to use a tree structure, a search in depth or length. I need ideas.

Comment: Are they always perfect chains or can there be overlap? For example can multiple elements with different inputs map to the same output?

Comment: yes they can overlaf, this answer is valid ex:  [ [1,4,5],[1,4,8] ]

Answer (score 0):

You could use a graph representation of this problem:

For each element `[n_element, l_input, l_output]`, you add vertices `l_input` and `l_output` to your graph (if not already present) and add an edge labelled `n_element` (from `l_output` to `l_input`).

Then, you look for paths through that graph. The resulting list is then given by the concatenation of edge labels.

Comment: You know the algoritm to do this? BFS? DFS? , I have the structure and it is a directed graph with cycles.

Comment: Enumerating all paths in a graph: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20262712/enumerating-all-paths-in-a-directed-acyclic-graph, but you can possibly be more clever than simply enumerating all and filtering them.